# NFS write permissions error

Tags: nfs, centos5

I've created an NFS share on one server to another (client) server and successfully mounted the folder (let's say /home/user/public_html/examplefolder) to the second (client) server.

I've logged in to the FTP account on the second (client) server and I'm attempting to write folders/files into the mounted NFS location (/home/user/public_html/examplefolder), but I get a permission denied error.

If I ssh into the client server as root I have full access to write into the NFS mounted location, so I know it has to be a user permission type of error.

I'm running CentOS 5 on both servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing a full user and group modification to get the users and groups on the client server to match up with the original server.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* you're running into the `root squash`, but I'm having trouble following all the clients and servers in your description, so here's a quick summary of `root squash`, you can better tell if this is what is happening:

NFS provides a [`root squash`](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_b11) option, to ensure that processes running as `root` on clients get no special privileges on the server. So the server 'squashes' all client `root` access to a `nobody` user on the server. (Which is why programs should *never* run as as `nobody`; the user id already has a specific use, and shouldn't be used for several unrelated purposes.)

Another possibility is your FTP server is confined with a tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SElinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/). Any of these [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tools can prevent an application from writing in specific locations, and might not yet be configured for your site. Check `dmesg(1)` output to see if there are any rejection messages, most or all these tools log to `dmesg(1)` if `auditd(8)` isn't running.

And, perhaps your ftp server has been [configured to deny writes](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html). Finding out *where* the `Access Denied` error message is coming from is important; you can `strace -o /tmp/ftp.out -f $(pidof ftpd)` (or whatever the process name is) to log all system calls and results to the `/tmp/ftp.out` file, which will give you an opportunity to see if `open(2)` calls are being rejected by the operating system or by the program.

Comment: sarnold, 

I've narrowed the issue down to be one of having separate UID and GID on my servers.   I'm mounting with the no_root_squash option which is why I'm able to write to the directory using the root account on the client server.

So now it seems my options are to change the UID and GID on one server to match that of the other, or to allow the UID and GID on the client server to write to the directory,  the latter of which I'm unsure of how to do.

Comment: @Thenayr, oh cripes :) mis-matched UIDs are a HUGE pain. I even spent an afternoon fighting exactly this problem with exactly that result. I must have repressed that memory -- sorry I didn't think of it sooner. In the end, we decided it was far easier to standardize uids across our company, since it was just two or three machines that needed modification.

Comment: I've tried using all_squash with an anonuid and anongid set to the correct uid and gid on the client server (say UID 500 and GID 500), but the mount still shows as the UID and GID of the main server (503 and 503).

Comment: @Thenayr, did you remount the export? Those changes will probably only take effect for _new_ mounts.

Comment: Sarnold - Yes, and restarted the NIS and portmap services.